# Laravel use custom php.ini with artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel-5

Is there a way to pass a custom php.ini to `artisan serve`?

I've tried

```
php -c path/to/my/custom/php.ini artisan serve
```

This does not seem to affect the web server though?

I know where my .ini files are, and I know how to edit them.  I just can't seem to make `artisan serve` use a custom .ini.

I also looked at:

```
php artisan serve --help
```

and it didn't seem to list any options for setting the .ini.

My reason is that I have a custom .ini file with XDebug enabled.
I want to be able to use it when debugging my Laravel app, but I don't want it enabled in my default php.ini

**UPDATE**

I've looked in

```
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php
```

for Laravel 5.6.25 at lines 49-57 and they have this:

```
 /**
 * Get the full server command.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function serverCommand()
{
    return sprintf('%s -S %s:%s %s',
        ProcessUtils::escapeArgument((new PhpExecutableFinder)->find(false)),
        $this->host(),
        $this->port(),
        ProcessUtils::escapeArgument(base_path('server.php'))
    );
}
```

So it looks like it is not possible to pass in a custom .ini unless the PhpExecutableFinder would include the -c argument for the .ini path?

**UPDATE 2**

I looked in the PhpExecutableFinder, and it looked as if you could set a PHP_BINARY environment variable to override, however this did not work.  It would be possible to have another complete copy of PHP that was configured for testing, but I'd rather have one PHP and just pass in my custom .ini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking into the Laravel framework code for Laravel 5.6.25, it appears the answer is No, this is not possible.  See question for more details.

Comment: you could also install xampp if your on windows, its a full proper local server environment. Then you don't need to use the limited builtin server.

Comment: yes, but I'd still have to twiddle with php.ini to turn on XDebug when I want to debug.  I don't want to leave it on all the time since it is so slooow :-)

Comment: yeah but then you can just open the php.ini from xampp and change it, have two , rename one, etc. Just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

- open console in `/public`
- `echo 'upload_max_filesize=256m' >> user.ini`
- `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -c user.ini '/absolute/path/to/laravel/project/server.php'`

I've looked into `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php` and it doesn't seem like Laravel itself is doing much more than this.

Checking with `phpinfo()` my `upload_max_filesize` shows `256m`